# How to run systemctl in a pod

Tags: kubernetes

Getting access denied error while running the systemctl command in a pod.

Whenever try to start any service, for example, MySQL or tomcat server in a pod, it gives access denied error.

Is there any way by which I can run systemctl within a pod.

Comment: see [blog](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2014/05/05/running-systemd-within-docker-container/), [blog](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2016/09/13/running-systemd-in-a-non-privileged-container/) and [blog](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/04/24/how-to-run-systemd-in-a-container/) and a summary of the [issues](https://lwn.net/Articles/676831/)

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem related to Docker, not Kubernetes.
According to the page [Run multiple services in a container](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/) in docker docs:

> It is generally recommended that you separate areas of concern by
>   using one service per container

However if you really want to use a process manager, you can try *supervisord*, which allows you to use *supervisorctl* commands, similar to *systemctl*. The page above explains how to do that:

> Here is an example Dockerfile using this approach, that assumes the
>   pre-written supervisord.conf, my_first_process, and my_second_process
>   files all exist in the same directory as your Dockerfile.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y supervisor
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/supervisor
COPY supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
COPY my_first_process my_first_process
COPY my_second_process my_second_process
CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

Comment: Thank you so much Victor for the detailed explanation. For sure, I will try it out.

Comment: Also [s6](https://skarnet.org/software/s6/)/[s6-overlay](https://github.com/just-containers/s6-overlay), it's lighter weight

Answer (score 1):

That's a rather short question. The 'systemctl' command does try to talk to the systemd daemon which is not running in a pod by default (it could however). Running multiple services is yet another question about service management. It both cases it could help to use a tool like the [docker-systemctl-replacement](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement) overwriting /usr/bin/systemctl and registering it as the init-CMD of the container.