# Kubernetes Pod: Failed to get D-Bus Connection

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, systemd, dbus

I have a docker containter based on centos/systemd. I run the container with

`docker run -d --privileged -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro <image>`

Then  i can access the container with:

`docker exec -ti <containerID> /bin/bash`

Then i can list all loaded units with the command `systemctl` . This works fine.

Now i want to deploy the image into a kubernetes cluster, this works also fine and i can access the running pod in the cluster via `kubectl exec -ti <pod> /bin/bash`

If i type now the command `systemctl` i get the error message

> Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted

How is it possible to make systemd/systemctl available in the pod?

**HINT:** Need systemd because of software running inside container, so supervisord is not an option here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56261077/how-to-run-systemctl-in-a-pod/56262303#56262303

Comment: need systemd because of the software running inside the container (Tableau Server)

Comment: In Docker and especially in Kubernetes, systemd can’t do 90% of the things it’s designed to do (and attempting to run systemctl in Docker is its own frequent source of confusion).  If systemd is really a hard requirement for this software, it’ll probably be easier to run it in a VM.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to volume mount `/var/lib/dbus` and `/etc/machine-id` and likely other paths but as David said, if your software is that heavily tied to systemd, you are likely solving the wrong problem

Comment: okay, sounds bad. what could be the right solution? LinuxContainer?

Answer (score 1):

It is a sad observation that the old proposal from Daniel Walsh (Redhat) is still floating around - which includes a hint to run a "privileged container" to get some systemd behaviour, by basically talking to the daemon outside of the container.

Drop that. Just forget it. You can't get that in a real cluster unless violating its basic designs.

And in most cases, the requirement for systemd in a container is not very strict when looking closer. There are quite a number of service-manager or an init-daemon implmentations for containers. You could try with the [docker-systemctl-replacement](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement) script for example.

Comment: Hi Mr. Draheim, i tried your docker-systemctl-replacement script. Thanks for sharing this script, it looks pretty interesting. But i am still having problems, if i use the script i am able to call ```systemctl``` in my centos-docker-container and will get a list of loaded units. But here is the problem: for installing my software (Tableau Server) in the container i need a dbus connection, and there is none. I receive the error ```Failed to create bus connection: No such file or directory```. Maybe any idea about this?

Comment: obviously, the replacement-script cuts the ties of "systemctl" to the systemd daemon. If the application itself has such a dependency then the script won't help. I don't know what the software is, however, but I do get the feeling that such an application is deeply integrated with system management - not software that is supposed to run in a container anyway that could be easily moved to other worker nodes in a cluster?

Answer (score 0):

The command to start systemd would have to be in a script in the container.  I use  `/usr/sbin/init` or `/usr/lib/systemd/systemd --systemd --unit=basic.target`.  Additionally you need start systemd with the tmpfs for /run to store runtime information.  Scripting it is not easy and Tableau is a good example of why it's being done.

Also, I recommend to NOT use --privileged at all costs, because it's a security risk plus you may accidentally alter or bring down the host with changes made inside the container.